# External link to an anchor within a PHP document not working

Tags: php, html

How do I format a link that will go to an anchor within a PHP document? 
For example:
http://chambervu.com/lososos/index.php#p=10 - does not display the intended result, however if I go to http://chambervu.com/lososos/index.php then once that page is displayed if I append "#p=10" then everything displays as intended. How would I form the link to display page 10 directly?

The "pages" in my index file  are setup like this:

```
 <li class="page" data-name="5">
 <div class="blah....blah"
 </div>
 </li>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="page" data-name="6">
 <div class="blah..blah"
 </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: fragments are usually `#foo` not `#foo=X` are you confusing them with url parameters (GET)?

Comment: I added how my code for how the pages are setup. I can't figure out how to form the URL for the link directly to a "page"

Answer (score 0):

Fragments point to an ID on the page, when you visit an HTML page with a fragment in the URL, the browser tries to find an element with a matching ID and scroll to it.

The javascript you have running on the page takes the fragment when it changes (after the page has loaded) and parses it to determine which page to show.

Linking directly to that page like you want would require some editting of the javascript at the very least.